# How to get pid from identical running processes and pipe the output into if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, process, pid, suspend

I want the script to find two identical processes that are currently running and pipe the PID of the process that matches a defined path in the variable `$procName` by using the `If($_.Path -eq $procName){` command.

After the correct process has been identified based on it's full file path found earlier, I want to use it's unique PID to check whether it is currently `suspended or not suspended`.

If all goes well in the current pipe then use it's output value to run one of two commands below:

```
If($_.Path -eq $procName) {
    Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner $myPID"
} Else {
    Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner -r $myPID"
}
```

My issue is the output is the same result no matter if the processes is currently suspended or not
`Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList /D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner -r 18960`

This is what I have so far:

```
$procName = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'
$procID = Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague' | Select-Object -Property Id,Path | ForEach-Object {
    If($_.Path -eq $procName){
        $myPID = $_.Id
        If(Get-ChildItem | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Responding -eq $false}) {
            Write-Host Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner $myPID"
            } Else {
            Write-Host Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner -r $myPID"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` doesn't return objects with a property `Responding`, which leads to `$null -eq $false` which is always `false` hence the `if` condition is effectively `if($null)` which then leads to the `else` condition being always called.

Comment: What command would you use in its place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code and respecting what Santiago has already pointed out, it looks like you are trying to take certain actions based on whether a particular process is responding.  If I have that right, I don't see the need for `Get-ChildItem`.  You could append the `Select-Object` command to include the `Responding` property then do the logic like:

```
$procName = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'

$procID = 
Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague' | 
Select-Object -Property Id, Path, Responding |
ForEach-Object {
    If($_.Path -eq $procName){
        $myPID = $_.Id
        If( !$_.Responding ) {        
            Write-Host Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner $myPID"
            } 
        Else {
            Write-Host Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner -r $myPID"
        }
    }
}
```

However, and unless there's more to the script, I don't think you need the `Select-Object` command at all:

```
$procName = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'

$procID = 
Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague' | 
ForEach-Object {
    If($_.Path -eq $procName){
        $myPID = $_.Id
        If( !$_.Responding ) {        
            Write-Host Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner $myPID"
            } 
        Else {
            Write-Host Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner -r $myPID"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, nothing will be in the `$procID` variable as the subsequent code doesn't write anything to the pipeline.  I left it in only because I don't know the full intent.

You could also shorten the code Somewhat by moving some of the If Logic into a `Where-Object` clause, See below with `$ProcID` removed.

```
$procName = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'

Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague' | 
Where-Object{ $_.Path -eq $procName }|
ForEach-Object {    
    If( !$_.Responding ) {        
        Write-Host Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner $($_.Id)"
        } 
    Else {
        Write-Host Start-Process cmd.exe -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList "/D /K pssuspend.exe -nobanner -r $($_.Id)"
    }
}
```

Note: I also used string expansion with a subexpression instead of assigning the `$myPID` variable.

Comment: This is a masterful response. Thank you so much. I did however have to make a tiny adjustment by changing the `Else {` to `ElseIf( !$_.Responding )`. Now it works properly. Thank you again so much!!!!

Comment: Glad it's working.  the "Responding" property is a simple Boolean value.  Theoretically, perfect for a simple If/Else.  Now I'm curious what necessitated If/ElseIf?

Comment: Here is the final script. https://pastebin.com/Zq6EHNkC

Comment: I took a look. As I suspected you can use `Else{}` instead of `ElseIf{}`.  Since `Responding` is a Boolean property, it can only be True or False.  Therefore, if you test the condition once you don't need to test it again. If `$_.Responding` is false the `Else{}` block will fire just the same.  `Else{}` would be slightly more efficient since you'd only ever test the condition once as opposed to sometimes once and sometimes twice in the current pattern.  Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: I modified it to demonstrate the point. You can see it [here](https://pastebin.com/VRj8QKHY). Note: Another good practice, is to put the expectedly more frequent condition earlier in the logic.  If you think the process will be responding more often than not then: `If( $_.Responding ){...} Else{...}`  If you think the process will not be responding more often not then negate the condition and swap the blocks. I.E. `If( -not $_.Responding ){...} Else{...}`. Note: For description's sake `-not` is the same as the `!` .  Let me know if anything.

Comment: Yep it is working as you said now. Wonder what the issue for me earlier was... Again thank you very much for the effort you put into this.